# What is the syntax for the unmanagedSources parameter in SBT for windows?

Tags: scala, sbt

Firstly my unmanaged source is not in the standard structure. It is:

```
src/com/domain/...
```

instead of

```
src/main/java/com/domain/...
```

Would this cause any problems?

Secondly I have tried a few options including

```
unmanagedSources in Compile += file("c:/codebase/src")
unmanagedSources in Compile += file("/codebase/src")
unmanagedSources in Compile += file("c:\\codebase\\src")
```

For all the above I get 'could not be found' errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should not cause problems, as long as you configure it correctly. You could try something like the following in your project settings:

```
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile <+= baseDirectory{ _ / "src"}
```

baseDirectory, as the name implies, is the base directory of your project, see [the Keys class](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/blob/0.10/main/Keys.scala#L65).